# Run lot of piplines in the same time

Tags: azure-data-factory

There is a solution if i want to run those piplines in the same time instead of doing it for each pipline[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a [trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers#triggers) at same time for all of your pipelines.

In the ADF portal:

[image]

Set the same time for trigger configuration:

[image]

If you want to execute them in the queue,you could use [execute pipeline activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-execute-pipeline-activity) which allows you to invoke another pipeline.

Comment: please, for the trigger i create a new piplines? and i put all the dataflow in this trigger or u mean a triger for each pipline?

Answer (score 1):

You could also leverage the lookup activity to lookup the pipeline using meta data or a pipeline parameter table and then use the set the for each loop to parallel processing so that it will process upto 50 pipelines at once.

See ForEach Article for more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-for-each-activity#parallel-execution